# swift firestore cannot check if documents value nil is

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

i have the following data structure in my cloud firestore db:
[image]

In my data parsing method i'm trying the following:

```
    if document.get("decisions") == nil{
                        object.decisions = document.get("decisions") as! [String: String]
                        }
```

The result is that the app is crashing, because my if clause allows to get the data, even if "decisions" is null

Comment: Hello, you may use if let or guard let.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that you would better like to make a safe check, alltogether with casting the type like so:

```
if let decisions = document.get("decisions") as? [String: String] {
    object.decisions = decisions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
if document.get("decisions") != nil{
    object.decisions = document.get("decisions") as! [String: String]
}
```

Comment: That's dangerous to do force casting. The app might still crash.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You can optimize my answer by editing.

Comment: Your answer is the same as the question isn't it?

Comment: No. I just change the conditional operator.

Comment: Ah my bad... ! :'D
Anyway you'd use _optional unwrapping_ in Swift. Here you end up fetching the "decisions" twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way which will convert null value to nil and won't cause crash in your app.

```
func nullToNil(value : AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {
    if value is NSNull {
        return nil
    } else {
        return value
    }
}

object.decisions = nullToNil(dict["decisions"])
```

or you can use

```
object.decisions = document.get("decisions") as? [String: String]
```